# How to export everything from every file in a directory?

Tags: node.js

Usually, I create an index.js file that exports everything from every file in a specific directory. like this:

```
export * from "./file1"
export * from "./file2"
export * from "./file3"
```

This is a common pattern in all of my projects. The downside of this approach is that whenever I create a new file in a directory I have to change its corresponding index.js file and export the new file. Now I'm trying to automate it and write a script that exports everything in every file in a directory.

after some googling, I came up with this:

```
import fs from "fs";

export let exp = {};

fs.readdirSync("./").forEach(function (file) {
  if (file.indexOf(".js") > -1 && file != "index.js") {
    const imp = require(`./` + file);
    exp = { ...exp, ...imp };
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work, maybe because I used the `require` function and that doesn't work with ES modules.

Also, I can't write something like this because I'm not allowed to use `export` in a function block.

```
export let exp = {};

fs.readdirSync("./").forEach(function (file) {
  if (file.indexOf(".ts") > -1 && file != "index.ts") {
    export * from ("./"+file);
  }
});
```

So I stock here. do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using a package like [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob). The glob package allows you to get all files inside a directory including those hidden within a subfolder.

Example usage:

```js
const glob = require("glob");

glob("**/*", function (err, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames
  // err is an error object or null
});
```

Comment: Actually, I want to "export" everything from all files in a directory. I don't have a problem finding files in a directory.